# Chrome issues with borders, moving elements etc

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've been having small issues with Chrome for quite some time now, and although I have discovered several Stackoverflow threads with similar issues I simply cannot find a fix.

---

The issues are as follows:

Certain elements borders appear as 1px (when in reality they should be 2px) and only fix themselves if I zoom in and out of the page, or Ctrl+A highlighting everything.

Other elements move slightly (either the element as a whole, or the text within them) when I hover over it.

Text also fails to appear sometimes and only reappears if I hover over a nearby element.

---

The issues are specific to Chrome, and I understand opacity (something used widely throughout my project) can be an issue with the browser. I found several threads that cited transforming, positioning relatively etc as solutions but I have had absolutely no luck. Sometimes when I load the page these issues don't exist and the elements appear normal (minus the text disappearing, that's pretty much a constant).

I've attached a video so you can see the issues first hand, but I am unsure what code I should attach. If there's a specific elements code you would find helpful to see I will happily upload it here. I can also send page files if that helps, but I'm not sure if it fits within the rules here.

Anyway, here's the video: http://sendvid.com/uvq3gpzo

Apologies for being so vague, as I know that's not particularly appreciated around here. I just have no idea where the issue lies and thought someone may have had something previous beforehand.

Thanks for taking the time to look into my problem and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Certainly possible that it's a Chrome behavior/bug, but you will be much more likely to get help if you can create a simple example that reproduces the behavior. If you can't reproduce the behavior in a simple example, that at least gives you a starting point to diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try to reproduce the problem on jsfiddle and update my post.